# Framework doesn't see a new column in production database table?

Tags: mysql, cakephp-2.1

I created a site with CakePHP responsible for displaying my CV. I would like to add a new feature relying on that if i still work at some company it should display text: "until now", if dont it should display a proper date. The problem is that when I adding a new column to my database named **`isActive`** and I set up value **1** to one of the entries (other entries have value **0**) page displays value 0 for all entries. This problem occurs on production server. On my development server everything is ok.

View:

```
         <?php 
          if ($experience['Experience']['isActive'] == 0  ) {
            echo $this->Time->format('Y.m', $experience['Experience']['dateEnd']);
            /*tmp*/ echo $experience['Experience']['isActive'];
          } else if($experience['Experience']['isActive'] == 1){
            echo 'until now';
          }  
        ?>
```

What may be a problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CakePHP caches the table structures. Delete the caches all will be good in the world again.

> If you make a change to your database schema when the debug level is 0, these model caches won’t be refreshed; if you get errors or unexpected behavior after making a database change, a likely fix is:

```
rm -f app/tmp/cache/models/*
```

As discussed [here](http://blog.mediarain.com/2009/09/the-dark-side-of-cakephp%E2%80%99s-automagic/).